# How to count in system verilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

In System Verilog I have multiple States in which some states are being used twice, how could I know if it's my first time passing by this state or that it's second time?

For example if it's my second time I want to end process and start again. if it's first time do it again.

Any idea can be helpful

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to execute some states twice, make them two different states. You can put the common logic parts inside a function.

```
always_ff @(posedge clk or posedge reset)
  if (reset) state <= IDLE else
  case (STATE)
    IDLE: if (start) STATE <= ST1;
    ST1: begin STATE <= ST2; fST(); end
    ST2: begin STATE <= IDLE; fST(); end
    default: STATE <= IDLE;
  endcase
function void fST;
// stuff that needs to be done
end function
```

If you need more than twice you can put in counter

```
always_ff @(posedge clk or posedge reset)
  if (reset) STATE <= IDLE else
  case (STATE)
    IDLE: if (start) begin STATE <= ST; counter <=0; end
    ST: begin 
          if (counter > N) STATE <= IDLE;
          counter <= counter + 1;
          // stuff that needs to be done
        end
    default: STATE <= IDLE;
  endcase
```

If you are separating your FSM into `always_comb` an `always_ff`, you will need a next state and next counter variable.

```
always_ff @(posedge clk or posedge reset)
         if (reset) STATE <= IDLE else
            begin
             STATE <= NXSTATE;
             COUNTER <= NXCOUNTER;
            end
always_comb
  case (STATE)
    IDLE: if (start) begin NXSTATE = ST; COUNTER <=0; end
    ST: begin 
          if (COUNTER > N) NXSTATE = IDLE;
          NXCOUNTER = NXCOUNTER + 1;
          // stuff that needs to be done
        end
    default: NXSTATE = IDLE;
  endcase
```